# Импорт csv через php

Tags: php, sql, csv

Пытаюсь импортировать csv не через phpmyadmin а через php запрос. Мне предложили вот такой вариант (LOAD DATA INFILE на хостинге закрыт)

```
$connection = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd)
or die(mysql_error());
$dbs = @mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or
die(mysql_error());


$nam="test.csv";
$separator=";";
$fop = fopen($nam , "r+");
$i=0;



while (!feof($fop))
{
$read = fgets($fop, 3000);
list($id, $name_group, $name, $price, $remainder, $description) = split($separator ,$read);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test FROM dbtest SET `id`='".$id."',  `name_group`='".$name_group."', `name`='".$name."',  `price`='".$price."',  `remainder`='".$remainder."',  `description`='".$description."' ");
$i++;
}
fclose($fop);
echo "Импортировано в базу записей: ".$i;
?>
```

В итоге скрипт пишет, что импортировано правильное количество записей, но база пустая. Никаких ошибок на хостинге в логах нет. Как понять почему не записываются данные?

Comment: у вас скрипт показывает сколько итераций "вставки" делается, а не сколько из них реально выполнено.

Comment: вам бы ознакомится с синтаксимом команды [`insert`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: забыл дописать, что `... FROM dbtest ...` там явно лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в sql запросе.

```
INSERT INTO test FROM dbtest SET `id`='".$id."'
```

Формат запроса на вставку в базу следующий:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

Я бы предложил не много переписать код используя PDO и стандартную функцию PHP для чтения csv файлов, например вот так:

```
$host      = 'localhost';
$db_name   = 'test';
$db_user   = 'root';
$db_passwd = '';
$file      = 'test.csv';
$delimiter = ',';
$verbose   = true;

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_passwd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO my1 (`id`, `name_group`, `name`, `price`, `remainder`, `description`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    if (!file_exists($file)){
        throw new Exception("File $file not found!");
    }
    $f = fopen($file, 'r+');

    $data = array();
    while($data[]=fgetcsv($f, 0, $delimiter)){}

    if (empty($data)) {
        throw new Exception("Empty data. Check the source file.");
    }
    $i=0;
    foreach ($data as $entry) {
        if (!is_array($entry) || empty($entry[0])) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($verbose){
            print "\nProcessing entry ID: ". $entry[0];
        }
        $stmt->execute($entry);
        $i++;
    }
    print "\n\n$i rows were successfully processed";

}
catch (Exception $e){
    print "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Исходный csv-файл:

```
1,group_1,name_1,400,,description_1
2,group_2,name_1,500,,description_2
3,group_3,name_1,600,,description_3
4,group_4,name_1,400,,description_4
5,group_5,name_1,500,,description_5
```

Результат:

[image: скриншот]